# How to get array inside json using key?

Tags: python, arrays, json

How to get only array from object using "15400001" key? Thanks

```
data = [{"15400001": [0, 7, 603, 607, 1655, 1661, 1703, 1706, 1823, 1825, 1826, 1827, 2423, 2471, 2475, 2477]}]
```

Comment: try this `json_data[0]['15400001']`

Comment: Thanks. I have try. But ı got "string indices must be integers" error. And ı tried without json.dumps() on array. It is working

Comment: First of you can't change a variable in between after someone comment if you change question then add a comment to notify the user which part of the question has updated. it's working perfect, maybe your data is a different format.

Comment: I'm sorry I asked with a hurry. I had the chance to correct it afterwards.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
data = [{"15400001": [0, 7, 603, 607, 1655, 1661, 1703, 1706, 1823, 1825, 1826, 1827, 2423, 2471, 2475, 2477]}]

print(data[0]["15400001"])
```

**Output :**

```
[0, 7, 603, 607, 1655, 1661, 1703, 1706, 1823, 1825, 1826, 1827, 2423, 2471, 2475, 2477]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic of `list` AND `dictionary` :-

```
data = [{"15400001": [0, 7, 603, 607, 1655, 1661, 1703, 1706, 1823, 1825, 1826, 1827, 
           2423, 2471, 2475, 2477]}]
my_dict = data[0]  # Getting 0 position of list AND in output we will get dictionary
my_dict['15400001']  # Getting value in dictionary from key.
```

- Here we have data which is of `list` type.
- Now we are iterating the `0` position of data list AND in output we will get dictionary.
- Now get values corresponding to key `15400001`, make sure that `15400001` should be string.

**Output**

```
[0, 7, 603, 607, 1655, 1661, 1703, 1706, 1823, 1825, 1826, 1827, 2423, 2471, 2475, 2477]
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
data[0]["15400001"]
```